# $G$ non-centerless group. How is $Z(\operatorname{Aut}(G))$ made?

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, automorphism-group

Let $G$ be a (possibly infinite) non-centerless group, *i.e.* such that $Z(G) \ne \lbrace e \rbrace$. Left and right multiplications establish the subgroups $\Theta:=\lbrace \theta_a \mid a \in G \rbrace \le \operatorname{Sym}(G)$ and $\Gamma:=\lbrace \gamma_a \mid a \in G \rbrace \le \operatorname{Sym}(G)$, such that:

- $G \cong \Theta$ and $G \cong \Gamma$;
- $\Theta\Gamma=\Gamma\Theta \le \operatorname{Sym}(G)$;
- $Z(G) \cong \Theta \cap \Gamma$;
- $\operatorname{Inn}(G)= \Theta\Gamma \cap \operatorname{Aut}(G)$.

Can we state anything about $Z(\operatorname{Aut}(G))$ and, in particular, about its relationships with $\Theta \cap \Gamma$ (inclusion, intersection, etc.)?

Comment: What do you mean by the second sentence? $G\cong \Theta\cong \Gamma$?

Comment: Yes, what you have written.

Comment: These are very strange conditions. What is the motivation?

Comment: It looks like you intend to have $\Theta$ and $\Gamma$ be the $G$ acting on itself by left and right translation. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, right. G is possibly infinite.

Comment: Well, you should add this information to the question.

Comment: You're right, done.

Comment: ${\rm Aut}(G)$ fixes the identity element, so it has trivial intersection with both $\Theta$ and $\Gamma$.